# How to make an anova table with letters for groupwise significant differences in R->latex?

Tags: r, latex, summarization

Is there a package in R that produces tables like this one:
[image]
Basically, given a dataset of factors and variables, produces a nicely-formatted table with pairwise t-tests and letters indicating significance of differences?

Dummy data:

```
var = c(rnorm(100,mean=1,sd=2),rnorm(30,mean=-1,sd=2),rnorm(50,mean=0,sd=4))
factor = as.factor(c(rep(1,100),rep(2,30),rep(3,50))
```

How would I take that dummy data and turn it into (one column of) the example table?

Comment: I don't think there's an out of the box solution for this. You would probably need to hand code this. See `xtable` package and its corresponding gallery: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/vignettes/xtableGallery.pdf

Comment: Yeah, thats what I was afraid of.  Making the thing into latex format is the easy part.  The hard part is coding the letters to indicate pairwise similarity/difference.  For example, what if f1 is similar to f2, but f3 is similar only to f2 and not f1?  The corresponding letters would be A, AB, and B.  While its quite simple to do manually, it gets quite tricky to automate, being recursive.  Most people who make these tables use JMP & etc.

Comment: If you hand code the latex output for this table, introducing letters (assuming you already have the grouping, using e.g. multcomp package), would probably be less trivial.

Answer (score 1):

---

**Disclaimer**

---

Not an exact answer but it could be good start!!! Use `tables` package.

```
library(Hmisc)
library(tables)
stderr <- function(x) sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))
latex(
  object = tabular((Species+1) ~ All(iris)* PlusMinus(mean, stderr, digits=1), data=iris)
 , title = "Test"
 , file=""
 , size = "small"
 , cdot = 3
 , here = TRUE
 , booktabs=TRUE
 , center="centering"
 )
```

---

**Output**

---

[image]

---

### **Edited**

You can obtain letters using `multcompView` package.

---

### **Code**

```
library(multcompView)

Sepal.Length.fm <- aov(Sepal.Length~Species, data=iris)
Sepal.Length.Letters <- data.frame("Letters"=multcompLetters(extract_p(TukeyHSD(Sepal.Length.fm)$"Species"))$"Letters")

Sepal.Width.fm <- aov(Sepal.Width~Species, data=iris)
Sepal.Width.Letters <- data.frame("Letters"=multcompLetters(extract_p(TukeyHSD(Sepal.Width.fm)$"Species"))$"Letters")

Petal.Length.fm <- aov(Petal.Length~Species, data=iris)
Petal.Length.Letters <- data.frame("Letters"=multcompLetters(extract_p(TukeyHSD(Petal.Length.fm)$"Species"))$"Letters")

Petal.Width.fm <- aov(Petal.Width~Species, data=iris)
Petal.Width.Letters <- data.frame("Letters"=multcompLetters(extract_p(TukeyHSD(Petal.Width.fm)$"Species"))$"Letters")

Letters <- cbind(Sepal.Length.Letters, Sepal.Width.Letters, Petal.Length.Letters, Petal.Width.Letters)
```

---

### **Output**

```
           Letters Letters Letters Letters
versicolor       a       a       a       a
virginica        b       b       b       b
setosa           c       c       c       c
```

Comment: Thanks!  That's a nice clean way to make the table.  But what about the letters?  As it is, you need to manually eye down the table and do the arithmetic to see if they are different.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `aggregate` function.

```
df = as.data.frame(cbind(var,factor))
aggregate(df$var, by=list(df$factor), t.test)

  Group.1         x
1       1  4.939821
2       2 -2.128924
3       3 -1.431482
```

If you want multiple tests to show up as new columns, you can create a new function as the final parameter.

Comment: Thanks.  The hard part is the letters, differing if two groups are statistically distinct.  A nice bonus would be clean exporting to latex format.  I probably spent an hour trying to figure out how to code that, and I'm quite sure someone already has figured it out.

Comment: What you mean by "the letters"?

Comment: see in that table example how there are letters next to the SD's?  Statistical difference is indicated by two groups not sharing any letters.  Some entries can have more than one letter if they are statistically indistinguishable from two other groups that are distinct from one another.

Comment: You may want to explain that a bit futher in the main question. I had no idea that was what you were hoping for! The table may be well formatted, but it's very confusing without explanation.